# Excluding both the minimum and maximum value

Tags: r, apply

I want to exclude the minimum as well as the maximum value of each row in a data frame. (If one of those value are repeated, only one should be excluded.)

I can exclude either the minimum, or the maximum, but not both.
I don't seem to find a way to combine those (which both work fine by themselves):

```
d[-which(d == min(d))[1]]

d[-which(d == max(d))[1]]
```

This doesn't work:

```
d[

  -which(d == min(d))[1] &

  -which(d == max(d))[1]

  ]
```

It gives the full row.

(I also tried an approach using *apply(d, 1, min/max)*, but this also fails.)

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do. Right now if ```d``` is a ```data.frame```  you are dropping entire columns, not rows or elements of these rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Remembered after looking at @Rich Pauloo's answer, we can directly use `which.max` and `which.min` to get index of minimum and maximum value

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) x[-c(which.max(x), which.min(x))])))

#  V1 V2 V3
#1 13 11  6
#2 15  8 18
#3  5 10 21
#4 14 12 17
#5 19  9 20
```

Here `which.max`/`which.min` will ensure that you get the index of first minimum and maximum respectively for each row.

---

Some other variations could be

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) 
            x[-c(which.max(x == min(x)), which.max(x == max(x)))])))
```

If you want to use `which` we can do

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) 
                x[-c(which(x == min(x)[1]), which(x == max(x)[1]))])))
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(25), 5, 5))
df

#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  3 13 11 16  6
#2 15  1  8 25 18
#3 24  5  4 10 21
#4 14 12 17  2 22
#5 19  9 20  7 23
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close! With `data.frame`s you need to use a comma within the brackets to accomplish [row-column subsetting](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/modules/subsetting-data/).

1. Use `which.max()` and `which.min()` to return the index of the max and min values of a vector, respectively.
2. Bind those indices into a new vector with `c()`.
3. Use `-` and the vector from 2. to subset your data frame for the desired rows.

Here's an example to copy/paste:

```
d <- data.frame(a = 1:5) # make example data.frame

d[-c(which.max(d$a), which.min(d$a)), ]

[1] 2 3 4
```

Comment: FYI: `which.max(d$a)` is identical to `which(d$a == max(d$a)`.

Comment: No, it's not. `which.max` and `which.min` return the first hit, `which(d$a == max(d$a))` returns all of them.

Comment: Right right. What I said is true only when there's **one** maximum. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: haha no worries! I'm in it for the puzzles and learning (and you reminded me  of a thing). =)

Comment: @RichPauloo: thanks, indeed, that's almost what I had, and I might even have been there at some point. But it still doesn't work… If I try it on a sample row of my data frame, the result is empty. (My plan is to replace the row number with i, and use a for loop and `rowMeans()` on the whole data set. This worked with the `apply()` solution mentioned above) `Data[22,5:13][-c(which.min(Data[22,5:13]), which.max(Data[22,5:13])), ]`

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the rows containing the min and max values of score as shown in the example data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(~name, ~score,
              'John', 10,
              'Mike', 2,
              'Mary', 11, 
              'Jane', 1,
              'Jill', 5)



df %>% 
  arrange(score)  %>% 
  slice(-1, -nrow(.))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name  score
  <chr> <dbl>
1 Mike      2
2 Jill      5
3 John     10
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) x[!x %in% range(x)]))
```